# Automatically input "yes" on the bash file

Tags: bash, cluster, user-input, slurm, redhat-satellite

Slurm is workload manager. There are two kinds of modes to run job, interactive(srun) and batch mode(sbatch).

When using interactive mode, one needs to leave the terminal open which may lead extra burden to the remote terminal(laptop).

However, sbatch mode just submit the bash script(*.sh) and can close the remote terminal. All the following steps are handled by the computing nodes.

When I run the executable program, it prompts "Are all filenames correct?" and expects "yes". What I want is that the script to automatically input "yes" for this prompt when running *.sh file so that the program can continue without interaction.

If you need any further clarification, please let me know.

Comment: What are you running? Many programs have a flag for this, like `-y`, but if you don't tell us what program you run, we cannot help.

Comment: Some programs can take the input from standard input. Try piping the output of `yes yes` to it... That's the `yes` utility executed with `yes` as its only argument.

Comment: You may have to use an expect script

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. I'm running FEM code and the following answer does solve my issue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
echo yes | your-program
yes yes  | your-program
```

Comment: Thanks very much, It really works. I test and find something differences between these two commands. It seems **echo yes | program** can end the program immediately and correctly after it was run, whereas  **yes yes | program** cannot. Could you please give me details on this issue?

Comment: The first will send one "yes"; the second sends as many as your program will read.